# Android load bitmap from this strange jpeg file

Tags: android

Everybody.
I have an issue, loading this strange jpeg file.
I tried with following code.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_images);
```

Some jpeg files is loaded without any issue.

This image is loaded without any issue.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/flyzrahi5n0w4ba/image_load_success1.jpg

This one is failed to load with error "skia --- decoder->decode returned false"
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwn8v7fvw6huje3/image_load_failed.jpg

I have tried to find the answer over the internet.
But I can't find the correct answer for it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your second image is a little bit larger that the first one. Could this be a memory issue?

Comment: You can see how to correctly load a large bitmap here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. I tried it and your second Image is loading ok.